# Ruby on Rails How to get an individual parameter from a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

I have a forms_for @conversation and when it is submitted I can grab all the fields from the form in the controller by params[:conversation].

Let's say I have a field in the form called :message. How would I grab that field in the controller? I tried: params[:conversation][:message] but returns nil.

Comment: try adding `raise params` to your controller action to see the contents of the params object.

Comment: `params[:conversation][:message]` is the usual way to do it. Check if you are getting the data in `:message` by `raise params.inspect`. Note that in a "normal" hash, there is a difference between symbol (`:message`) and string (`"message"`), though in case of the special `params` hash this should not be a problem since it is a special kind of hash called `HashWithIndifferentAccess` meaning that it will conside a string and symbol hash key to be the same for the purposes of getting values from the hash.